# How to add single quote to only word which has dot in the middle (or anywhere except begining) of the word using sed/awk on MAC (no gnu support)?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Part of input file with many lines:

```
.class xyz.com class.name_1 and xxx.co .class class.man_3 'abc.name_4' #id
#id .class abc.name class.name and class.name_2 class.name_3 .class class.dragon class.xyz
```

Desire Output:

```
.class 'xyz.com' 'class.name_1' and 'xxx.co' .class 'class.man_3' 'abc.name_4' #id
#id .class 'abc.name' 'class.name' and 'class.name_2' 'class.name_3' .class 'class.dragon' 'class.xyz'
```

should handle this input as well:

```
.xxx-xxxx.xxxx-xxxx 
.xxxx.xxxx
xic.aco-eiopw-ejek.cojdj
```

output

```
.xxx-xxxx.xxxx-xxxx 
.xxxx.xxxx
'xic.aco-eiopw-ejek.cojdj'
```

I tried using this `sed "s/^\(.* \)\(.*\.\)\(.* \)/\'1\2\3'/g"`
It gives following output:

```
'1class.name_4 #id '
'1class.name_4 '
....
```

Comment: .class has dot in it, should it not be quoted?

Comment: word starting with dot should not be quoted.

Comment: Change my post so words with dot at end will be quoted as well.  If its OK, up vote it and accept it as an answer.

Comment: Since you change input several times, its hard to give a good answer.

Comment: sed -E "s/\b[a-z]*\.[a-z\-]*|\b[a-z]*\.[a-z]*.[0-9]/'&'/g" looks like this one works 
with class.name-cow as well. Added \-

Comment: Does not work.  Double quote around abc.name_4 and will fail with uppercase letter.  Does not my work?

Comment: sed -E "/^[^#]/s/(\S+\.\S*)/'\1'/g" its working on https://sed.js.org/index.html but its not working on Mac no gnu  sed

Comment: Why did you not post this info on my post or in your post, I do not see that this is on Mac?  What about this? `sed "/^[^#]/s/\(\S+\.\S*\)/'\1'/g;s/''/'/g"`

Comment: sed "/^[^#]/s/\(\S+\.\S*\)/'\1'/g;s/''/'/g" also does not work in Mac. @Jotne

Comment: Can you use `awk`?  you have tagged the question with `awk` and `sed`

Comment: yes I have been practicing on both awk and sed right now.

Comment: Added and `awk` version.  Much more powerfull than `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `awk` version

```
awk -v s="'" '!/^#/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~"^[^.].*[.]" && $i!~"^"s) $i=s$i s}1' file
.class 'xyz.com' 'class.name_1' and 'xxx.co' .class 'class.man_3' 'abc.name_4' #id
#id .class abc.name class.name and class.name_2 class.name_3 .class class.dragon class.xyz
```

`s="'"` # set s to singe quote (simpler to handle this way)
`!/^#/`  # run next part only if line does not start with #
`{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`  # Loop trough all fields on the line
`if($i~"^[^.].*[.]"`  # Test if field has an dot, but not as first character
`&& $i!~"^"s` # And it also does not start with single quote (the value of s)
`$i=s$i s` # Add single quote on both side of field
`1`  # print the line (always true)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed -E "s/(\S+\.\S*)/'\1'/g" file
.class 'class.name' 'class.name_1' and 'class.name_2' .class 'class.name_3' 'class.name_4' #id
```

If you like to ignore line starting with `#`

```
sed -E "/^[^#]/s/(\S+\.\S*)/'\1'/g" file
```

Edit
Workaround to handle already quoted words.

```
sed -E "/^[^#]/s/(\S+\.\S*)/'\1'/g;s/''/'/g" file
.class 'xyz.com' 'class.name_1' and 'xxx.co' .class 'class.man_3' 'abc.name_4' #id
```

Without the -E option.

```
sed "/^[^#]/s/\(\S+\.\S*\)/'\1'/g;s/''/'/g" file
```

Comment: How to make this work in Mac without installing gnu sed?

And following is failing for sed  -E "/^[^#]/s/(\S+\.\S*)/'\1'/g"
.xxx-xxxx.xxxx-xxxx

 or 
.xxxx.xxxx

it should not add quote.

Comment: looks like this will work sed -E "/^[^#\.]/s/(\S+\.\S*)/'\1'/g" for .xxx-xxxx.xxxx-xxxx or .xxxx.xxxx

Comment: unable to run this in Mac terminal. Only able to run in https://sed.js.org/index.html